# data will be reset after fwrite with serialize php

Tags: php, serialization, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying to save all daily visitors IP addresses in text file. Problem is, i don't know why after some IP addresses, all IP's will be remove!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running with errors turned off or not looking at the php error log.

You missed a `[]` on the `$FileIPs['TIME']` line.

Unless you have written a function called `Write()`, in which case show us the code for it, I dont know of a PHP function called `Write()`. So you are probably not actually writing the data back to the file anyway.

You used `file_get_contents` to read the file, why not use `file_put_contents` to rewrite it, like so.

```
//Add New IP To File
if($NewVisitor){
  $FileIPs['TIME'][] = $Today;
  $FileIPs['HISTORY'][] = $IP;
  print_r($FileIPs);
  //Write Function
  file_put_contents(FILE_HISTORY, serialize($FileIPs));
}
```

Comment: i tried file_put_contents, but same problem. i'll update my code and adding the Write() function and i don't have any error in php error log

Comment: Ok before writing out the newly serialized array, dump it to the screen so you can see if you are actually adding data to the array before re-serializing it. See changed answer.

Comment: some time it shows the new data and some time not. for example, after changing IP manually it does not show the new data, or after adding some new IP's too. is it possible to edit saved serialized data manually?

Comment: Yes its just a text file, but it is rather fiddly and easy to make mistakes

Comment: can i upload the file then you just look at the source? if you have time :(

Comment: Sorry no time even for a simple debugging, its all down to you now.